# When to use UIViewController vs UIView when animating?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

When should a `UIView` be placed over the current views (in the same controller) vs adding a whole new `UIViewController`?

I know that the `UIViewController` manages `UIView`s, but imagine that you wanted something to popup when a user selected something. What decides whether a `UIView` be animated and added to the current controller (using `animateWithDuration`), or a new `UIViewController` with a custom transition?

Twitter example:

1. http://i.giphy.com/3o7TKKcmcIz76ONXFe.gif - Not sure if this is a UIView added to the existing controller, or if it's a new controller. I just tap the image, and it pops up. I then slide down and slowly move the image off the screen (interactively).

Spotify examples:

1. http://i.giphy.com/3oz8xRSkmxbcVqPZf2.gif - Probably a UIViewController. I'm grabbing the bottom bar and sliding it up. I then slide down on the album cover.
2. http://i.giphy.com/3oriO7SjzB5GfThx60.gif - Possibly a UIView? Happens when I press and hold a album cover.

What determines when one should be used over the other? It would probably be helpful if you explained the examples. Thanks.

Comment: Animating doesn't matter as much as the more basic question, when to use a vc vs. a view.  Having made that decision, the app can either animate the vc's view or the view based on which is chosen.  On the basic question, I think it's a fuzzy line.  Indicators for a vc are: occupies full screen, has many subviews of it's own, has significant user interaction of it's own, handles other events from the system, etc.  Views are simpler, show less and do less.

Comment: On the links, I'd be inclined to use a vc for all of them.

Comment: @danh vc are not necessarily occupying full screen. The biggest benefit of using vc and add vc as a children of other vc is sharing view related method such as `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: @Ryan - yes, but I'm not sure why you direct the comment to me.  I didn't say vc's must occupy the full screen.

Comment: @danh because you said so. `Indicators for a vc are: occupies full screen`